# PowerShell's equivalent of LINQ All, or how can I verify all the items in the collection are equal to specific value?

Tags: linq, powershell

I have a collection of items, which I build from a regex match, like this:

```
$collection = $input | foreach {
    if ($_ -match $regex) {$matches} else { return }
} | 
  Select-Object –Property @{name='command'; expression={$_.command} },
                          @{name='id';      expression={$_.id} }
```

(sorry if that's not the best way to do this, I'm learning PowerShell :))

What I'd like to do is to make sure all the `command` properties in this `$collection` are equal to the same command, e.g. `"myCommand"`, how can I do that?

ff this were C#, I'd probably do something like:

```
if (collection.All(item => item.Key == "myCommand")) { ... }
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this in PowerShell?

Comment: All the same (whatever the command is) or all equal to a given command?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin the latter. I updated the title, thanks!

Comment: My first thought is `($collection | ? { $_.command -ne 'myCommand' }).Length -eq 0`, but that's kind of clunky, I'll think a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pointed to this [LINQ Module for PowerShell](https://github.com/fschwiet/linq-powershell/), which allowed me to do simply:

```
$collection | Linq-All { $_.command -eq "myCommand" }
```

Which is just what I needed! More examples [here](https://github.com/fschwiet/linq-powershell/blob/master/josheinstein.com_blog_linq-for-powershell.txt).

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet returns `$true` when all items in array are equal. What it does is:

1. iterate through an array of objects using ForEach-Object
2. compare each one with the previous using the Compare-Object cmdlet.

If Compare-Object returns non-null at least once, which means that the two objects being compared are different, the snippet will return `$false`, otherwise `$true`.

Applying the snippet to the array @(1,1,1,1,1,2) will return `$false` because of the last item.

```
@(1,1,1,1,1,2) |
    ForEach-Object -Begin { $last = $null; $result = $true } {
        if ($last -ne $null -and $result -and (Compare-Object $last $_) -ne $null) {
            $result = $false
        }
        $last = $_
    } -End { $result }
```